# PowerMockito verify private method called x times

Tags: java, junit, powermock, powermockito

I'm using `PowerMockito` and `spy` to mock private methods:

```
final SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
final SomeClass spy = PowerMockito.spy(someClass);

PowerMickito.doReturn("someValue", spy, "privateMethod1");
final String response = Whitebox.invokeMethod(spy, "anotherPrivateMethod");

// I can now verify `response` is of the correct data
// But I also want to verify `privateMethod1` was called x times or so
```

I cannot figure out how to verify that my method was called x times.

**Side note**

Is it better to just make all my private methods `protected` and then extend that class in my test class and do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This will do.

```
PowerMockito.doReturn("someValue", spy, "privateMethod1");
final String response = Whitebox.invokeMethod(spy, "anotherPrivateMethod");
assert(response)
verifyPrivate(spy, times(1)).invoke("anotherPrivateMethod", "xyz");
```

I am assuming your private method(anotherPrivateMethod) takes one argument "xyz". Which you can modify according to your private method declaration.

Comment: I still want to validate the response from the invoked method. How would I get the result of the invoke from your example?

Comment: @Kousha as you can see, the invoked method via Whitebox returns output value of the invoked method(anotherPrivateMethod in this case). There is an assert that comes right after it